# "'Call'-Function does not match signature of base method in class 'Network'" - building an A3C Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I'm trying to test an A3C-model that I was provided through this tutorial:
https://medium.com/tensorflow/deep-reinforcement-learning-playing-cartpole-through-asynchronous-advantage-actor-critic-a3c-7eab2eea5296

First, since the algorithm doesn't recognize all the packages (although installed), I tried to refer to them in different approaches:

- from tensorflow import keras (didn't work)
- from tensorflow._api.v1 import keras (worked)

Now I have the following base-concept of an A3C-model:

class ActorCriticModel(keras.Model):

```
def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):                  
    super(ActorCriticModel, self).__init__()
    self.state_size = state_size
    self.action_size = action_size
    self.dense1 = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')
    self.policy_logits = layers.Dense(action_size)
    self.dense2 = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')
    self.values = layers.Dense(1)

def call(self, inputs):
    # Forward pass
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    logits = self.policy_logits(x)

    v1 = self.dense2(inputs)
    values = self.values(v1)
    return logits, values
```

model = ActorCriticModel()

Providing the packages:

- from keras import layers (which is recognized as used package)
- from keras.layers import Input (isn't recognized as used package)

I currently face the problem that inputs in my model aren't "matching signature of base method in class 'Network'".

How do I solve this?

About the versions of the programs and API's that I work with:

- Python 3.7.3
- Tensorflow 1.13.1
- Keras 2.3.1

Comment: In which OS are you trying to implement the code?

Comment: It's in Windows 10. Might it be better to implement on Linux?

Comment: No, I had the same issue on Ubuntu (TF 2.0)

Comment: Can confirm, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS throws out same issues